# Computer Vision Libraries for PHP

Tags: computer-vision, image-processing, face-detection

Are there any computer vision libraries in PHP, or any server-side programming languages?

If not, maybe we can make a list of some -already implemented- methods (Viola Jones face detector, landmark detector etc.) to help someone who wants to implement such a library?

Answer (score 2):

Someone's written a php interface to OpenCV - https://github.com/mgdm/OpenCV-for-PHP, though I haven't tested it.

As you've tagged face detection I'll also mention that someone has written a php interface specifically to the face detection functionality of openCV too; http://www.xarg.org/project/php-facedetect/

Alternatively you could try (and this would probably offer more flexibility);

[Note: this is just a short list; searching e.g. "python image processing" will give more options]

**Python**

- [OpenCV bindings](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_tutorials.html)
- [scipy.ndimage](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html)
- [Scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/)

**Java**

- [OpenCV bindings](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html)
- [ImageJ api](http://imagej.nih.gov/ij/developer/api/)

**C++**

- [OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/refman.html)
- [CImg](http://cimg.sourceforge.net/)

[The top answer to this question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/good-language-for-computer-vision) also has a good discussion, though I'd be careful about using Matlab in this instance as you might fall foul of their licence restrictions.